# C# Xamarin - Directory.GetFiles returns an empty array

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am attempting to retrieve the filepath for each PDF within multiple folders in Android external storage, as a List. I can retrieve the paths for each child directory, but when I use `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf")` an empty array is returned. I'm testing this on a Samsung Tab A7 and each of the child folders contain between 1 and 160 PDFs. There are no exceptions thrown, the List just returns with an empty String array for each folder.

[Edit]

1. localPath is passed in as the top-level directory. (See second code block for how it is generated)
2. allFiles is created to store an array of files from each directory. It should be initialised with any files in the top-level directory.
3. subDirectories is storing the folder structure a layer down. (getDirectories is working successfully for this).
4. The code inside my foreach statement is where the problem lies. `allFiles.Add(Directory.GetFiles(subDir, "*.pdf"));` returns an empty array even though there are files in those folders. I have tried changing the search pattern to "*" but experienced the same problem.

[End of edit]

Here is the method I am using:

```
private List<string[]> GetAllFiles(string localPath)
        {
            List<string[]> allFiles = new List<string[]>
            {
                Directory.GetFiles(localPath, "*.pdf")
            };

            string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(localPath, "*");

            if (subDirectories.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string subDir in subDirectories)
                {
                    allFiles.Add(Directory.GetFiles(subDir, "*.pdf"));
                }

            }

            return allFiles;
        }
```

In order to get the path to the parent folder, I am using:

```
public string GetPath()
        {
            string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + File.Separator + "parent" + File.Seperator;
            return path;
        }
```

In my AndroidManifestFile I have included:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What is path or localPath?

Comment: localpath is the result of Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + parent folder name. The absolute path it uses here is: "/storage/emulated/0/parent/". 

So getFiles() cannot access the folder I am trying to use?

Comment: Please edit your post. Show step by step what you do. Parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified by using Directory.EnumerateFiles(), however the main problem turned out to be that while `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` was included in the manifest, it had not been requested in the program. This is neccesary to access external storage files on android 11.

By checking `if (!Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)`
we can check whether all file access has been enabled.

In the end my working solution was the following:

```
public List<string> GetAllFiles(string path)
        {
            if (!Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAppAllFilesAccessPermission,
                Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + Application.Context.PackageName));

                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }


            List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();

            allFiles.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

            return allFiles;
        }
```

This method also appends the files it finds to a List variable, making it easier to work with.